# Error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=7.0.12.0'" when creating Razor Page in .NET 7.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, code-generation, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

## I'm encountering an error when attempting to create a Razor Page in my .NET 7.0 project using EF Core. The error message states:

[image: How to fix that error]

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I'm using .NET 7.0 and Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.6.4

Comment: Try to add the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` Version="7.0.12.0"

Answer (score 0):

In .net 7 , we don't need to add the packages before Scaffold the model, it will add packages with Scaffold.

And generate below code:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.12" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.12">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.11" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

You can read [Scaffold the movie model .net7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model) and [Scaffold the movie model .net6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-the-movie-model) to konw more.

result:
[image]